# Ember.js - Reference parent view's controller variable in partial

Tags: ember.js, controller, partials

I have a template `home.hbs` that renders a partial `{{partial "my_partial"}}`

Now, in `my_partial`, a reference to `this` gives me `<app@controller:home::ember442>`

But what I really need to do is grab a variable defined in `HomeController` inside the partial with something like: `{{this.variable_name}}` where `variable_name` is defined in `HomeController` as:

```
variableName: function(){
  return some_value;
}.property('variableName')
```

Is there a way to do this in Ember? Let me know if you need clarification

Comment: can you throw this up on jsbin?

Answer (score 0):

`partial` does not change context. that means (as you noticed by checking `this`) that the context whitin the partial is the same `HomeController` the only problem I see, is that you are `variableName` as an attribute that it self depends on `variableName`,

When you use `.property` it takes the *other* properties this will depend upon as argument. that means that the value on `variableName` can change when the properties it depends upon have changed.

If your property does not depend on other properties, you can leave the arguments empty.

```
variableName: function(){
  return someValue;
}.property()
```

And in your template instead of `{{this.variableName}}` use `{{variableName}}`

Comment: So, can you tell me how I can declare it as an attribute?

Comment: its int he answer, you need to add `.property()` at the end of the method definition.

Comment: I changed my answer, hopefully that helps

Comment: This doesn't change anything in my situation. Any other ideas?